# Single Sign On for Web Application using Jsf and Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, jsf, cloud

I have developed an application using JSF,Spring and Spring Security with JPA. Which is working perfectly.
This application is to be shared by different companies with their separate database (same structure) hosted in the cloud.

Now my dilemma is, 
how to provide the same login page which will authenticate and dynamically set the database name in jpa persistance for the respected company. So each user will have different application but infect it is same cloud application.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What o can think of is that it is possible if you create entitymanager after starting the app. When a user tried to login, it should be recognised to which company it belongs and then accordingly, database properties should be loaded. But again the question is how will be the company for user will be identified.